# I need a (preferably javascript) example of Google Url shortener Api

Tags: google-url-shortener

I'm working on a 'Place your Marker and get its URL' function for a Google Maps Page.
The URLs produced are similar to :

http://www.fuerteventura-maps.com/marker11.html?=28.4234731,%20-14.014550299999996=14=Sample%20Marker=roadmap

I'd like to somehow have the URL automatically shortened using the Google URL Shortener so that the URL the user needs to copy is just:
http://goo.gl/ZEQ7u

I've looked at the documentation but it assumes greater knowledge than I possess. Unlike the Maps Api documentation there are no simple examples for me to adapt.

Can anyone point me to a simple Google URL Shortener demo please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Twas a little bit of a struggle for me but this page gave me something to download and work with.

I've now got exactly what I was after:

[Url shortener demo](https://github.com/tommcfarlin/gURLDemo)

(At first I was getting errors so I emailed the author - Tom McFarlin . and within an hour he had replied and corrected the fault in his code. Thanks Tom.)

Comment: for anyone interested - the site now incorporates the get url , plus get short url, plus get qr code - and some other more conventional features - mostly set for fuerteventura  [link]http://www.fuerteventura-maps.com

Answer (score 0):

The current samples provided by Google show only how to expand a shortened URL.

What you're looking for can be found [here](http://copaseticflow.blogspot.in/2012/06/javascript-google-url-shortener-client.html).

The problem, as the blogger points out is,

> "If you follow the documentation on the **insert** method, (the method for getting a shortened url from a long one), there is a reference to a rather nebuluos Url resource required argument. It's not at all clear how to create one of these in Javascript."